# Visiting all strings by swapping

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

Consider the following strings

```
  'dcabab',
  'cdabab',
  'dacbab',
  'adcbab',
  'cadbab',
  'acdbab',
  'dbacab',
  'bdacab',
  'dabcab',
  'adbcab',
  'badcab',
  'abdcab',
  'cbadab',
  'bcadab',
  'cabdab',
  'acbdab',
  'bacdab',
  'abcdab',
  'dabacb',
  'adbacb',
  'badacb',
  'abdacb',
  'adabcb',
  'abadcb',
  'cabadb',
  'acbadb',
  'bacadb',
  'abcadb',
  'acabdb',
  'abacdb',
  'cababd',
  'acbabd',
  'bacabd',
  'abcabd',
  'abacbd',
  'ababcd'
```

If you are currently at one of those strings, you can attempt to make another one by swapping any pairs of characters. For example, you can go from 'dcabab' to 'cdabab' by swapping the first two characters. This is good because the characters that are swapped are right next to each other, that is of distance one.

## The puzzle

Find a way to go from one of the strings of your choosing to all the other strings by doing one swap per new string.  That is start at a string, do one swap making a new string from the list, then do another swap from the new string making another string from the list and so on.  You must only ever visit strings from the list.

For those who like graphs, you can think of the strings as forming nodes in a graph and two nodes being connected by an edge if you can get from one string to another by a single swap.

Your goal is to make the distance between characters that you swap as small as possible. If you only ever need to swap adjacent characters then you have  perfect solution.

If it can't be done, please explain why.

Comment: So we can just ignore the last 'cd', and treat the strings as 6 characters long? Why did you choose to show the last 'cd'?

Comment: And why specifically these strings? I would expect for example 'abcdbacd' there as well.

Comment: @Lezzup I cleaned up the list of strings, thanks. They derive loosely from https://oeis.org/A278990

Comment: @Lezzup 'bacdab' is equivalent to 'abcdba' up to bijections which is why  'abcdbacd' was not included. (This is for an earlier version where every string unnecessarily had cd at the end)

Comment: Is there any restriction to not visit the same string twice?

Comment: @justhalf No. That would be interesting but more difficult. If you can do it that way it's definitely a bonus though.

Comment: I think this was downvoted because it really boils down to a shortest-path problem, of which we already have algorithms like Dijkstra or A*.

Comment: @newQOpenWid It is TSP, much harder than shortest path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By introducing a dummy node that is adjacent to all other nodes, we have a traveling salesman problem on a graph with $37$ nodes and $130$ edges.  The distance between nodes is $0$ if either node is the dummy and otherwise is the distance between the two swap characters.  These distances are thus in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.  The minimum total distance in a tour turns out to be:

> $36$, with $2$ edges of distance $0$ (for the dummy), $34$ edges of distance $1$, and $1$ edge of distance $2$

Here is such a tour,

> with the distance-$2$ edge highlighted:
>  $$\text{DUMMY},acabdb,acbadb,acbdab,acdbab,cadbab,cdabab,dcabab,dacbab,adcbab,adbcab,abdcab,abcdab,bacdab,bcadab,cbadab,cabdab,cabadb,cababd,acbabd,abcabd,bacabd,bacadb,abcadb,abacdb,abacbd,\color{blue}{ababcd,abadcb},abdacb,badacb,badcab,bdacab,dbacab,dabcab,dabacb,adbacb,adabcb,\text{DUMMY}$$

> To see that it is impossible to have a shorter tour, consider the subgraph with $37$ nodes and $89$ edges that have distances at most $1$.  Removing the following $13$ nodes yields a graph with $14$ connected components: $$\text{DUMMY},abacdb,abcabd,abcdab,abdacb,acbadb,adbacb,adcbab,bacadb,badcab,cabdab,cdabab,dabcab$$ Having more connected components than removed nodes is a well-known sufficient criterion for non-Hamiltonicity.

> The following $11$ nodes, the removal of which yields $12$ connected components, provide an even shorter certificate of non-Hamiltonicity: $$\text{DUMMY},abacdb,abcabd,abcdab,abdacb,acbadb,adbcab,bacadb,badcab,cabdab,dabcab$$

Comment: That's a great solution. What software did you use?

Comment: Thanks. I used the OPTMODEL procedure in SAS.

Comment: Nice, this also doesn't visit any node twice.